# Can Linux file permissions be modified in Ant

Tags: linux, ant, installation, debian, file-permissions

Is there any way to set file ownership and permissions using **Ant** in **Linux**?  I found the **Ant** `chmod` and `chown` tasks but they are only for Unix.
 I'm trying to add a Debian installer through **Ant** and **ant-deb-task** and after moving all required files to a deploy directory, I need to set their ownership and permissions.

Comment: Have I tried chmod and chown? Yes, they do nothing.

Comment: "I found the Ant chmod and chown tasks but they are only for Unix." -- that should not be the case, if they don't work on your distro, check your path

Comment: Really? The [online doc](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/chmod.html) says "_won't do anything unless it detects it is running on a Unix system_" and "_you can use the task's os attribute and set its value to your current os_" ...but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: since your approval below was posted after the most recent comment above, with which it sort of contradicts, i will take it as final

Comment: Sorry if that was confusing.  The approval was posted as it does solve my problem but the chown/chmod tasks would have been nicer and far less long winded.

Comment: chmod nd chown tasks have worked for me on linux. There must be something weird with your ant. Try installing from official page and run a test again.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "They are only for Unix."  Linux is Unix for all intents and purposes.  I'm not sure why the ant tasks didn't work for you, but I don't think that's the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have access to Ant on Linux currently (will do at home) but try to see if this works

```
<target name="chmod_task">
  <exec executable="chmod">
    <arg value="755"/>
    <arg value="/path/filename.ext"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: This seems to work ok but it would make my build.xml crazy long.  Guess I'll just have to deal with it.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use the built in Ant chmod task - http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/chmod.html

Single file:

```
<chmod file="${dist}/start.sh" perm="ugo+rx"/>
```

multiple files:

```
<chmod perm="g+w">
  <fileset dir="shared/sources1">
    <exclude name="**/trial/**"/>
  </fileset>
</chmod>
```